# Upload file automatically once browse without any button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have requirement to browse and upload the file. Here we put a fileupload control and to upload put one button, on button click the file should be uploaded.

Now the task is to upload the file automatically once browse the file without any button click events.

Please give me some inputs to do the same.

thanks

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this myself, modified the code as below

$(document).on('change', '#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>', function () {
                $('#<%= btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(); });

More important thing here is we should not make the button control visible=false. keep width to very less asmuchas it cannot visible.

Thanks
Rehman

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try handling the onchange event of the fileupload control ?

```
$("fileUpload").change(function(event){
......
});
```

Comment: So, doesn't this work ? what's the issue ? Can u share the code ? Is the event handler not getting invoked ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991824/how-to-automatically-upload-file-after-file-has-been-chosen?rq=1

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" class="multi" Width="200px" />                                                                                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Height="21px" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"                                              Text="Upload" Width="80px" CssClass="NormalButton" OnClientClick="return ValidateFile();"                                                                                    Visible="false" />

Comment: the script is $(document).ready(function () {$(document).on('change', '#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>', function () { $('#<%= btnUpload.ClientID %>').trigger('click');});});

Comment: I am not familiar with ASP.net, i will suggest you check the HTML being generated.That will give you a clear picture of what's going on.Or you can share it here also.