# Upload file directly after browsing it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have created a simple method that upload files to server when button is clicked. This method is working perfectly on button click, but I need to make it an automatic upload directly when user chooses file from his computer. Any idea about how can I make it? 
This is my asp code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate >
       <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
       <br/>
       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
       <br/>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
       <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Below is the code behind:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/")
        Dim fileOK As Boolean = False
        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
            Dim fileExtension As String
            fileExtension = System.IO.Path. _
                GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower()
            Dim allowedExtensions As String() = _
                {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif"}
            For i As Integer = 0 To allowedExtensions.Length - 1
                If fileExtension = allowedExtensions(i) Then
                    fileOK = True
                End If
            Next
            If fileOK Then
                Try
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path & _
                         FileUpload1.FileName)
                    Label1.Text = "File uploaded!"
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Label1.Text = "File could not be uploaded."
                End Try
            Else
                Label1.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type."
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991824/how-to-automatically-upload-file-after-file-has-been-chosen) handle the onchange and sumit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a dummy LinkButton to the aspx page. Leave the Text empty so it is not visible to the user but does exist in the HTML.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then add a javascript listener to the FileUpload control in code behind that will do the PostBack of LinkButton1 when a change occurs.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "__doPostBack('" + LinkButton1.UniqueID + "','')");
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //handle the file upload
}
```

VB

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    FileUpload1.Attributes.Add("onchange", ("__doPostBack('"  _
                    + (LinkButton1.UniqueID + "','')")))
End Sub

Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'handle the file upload
End Sub
```